# SAS data update / manipulation

Tags: arrays, sas, data-manipulation, proc-sql

I am relatively new to SAS programming but I have been picking up the basics over the past few months, and its served my needs. However I am currently having trouble and would like some help. I am trying to update a data base and create two new variables that will help with tracking the updates. So I've simplified my problem with the following tables:

Source Table

```
ID      Record_ID   Correction_ID
0001    A001    
0002    A002    
0003    A003        A001
0004    A004        A002
0005    A005    
0006    A006        A004
```

Target Table

```
ID          Record_ID   Correction_ID   Original_Record     Count
0001        A001                            A001                0
0002        A002                            A002                0
0003        A003            A001            A001                1
0004        A004            A002            A002                1
0005        A005                            A005                0
0006        A006            A004            A002                2
```

Correction_ID indicates the record that the current one is trying to correct / amend.

Count indicates the update number on the original record.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Proc SQL codes that I tried but did not work:

```
ID          Record_ID   Correction_ID   Original_Record     Count
Table 1
0001        A001                            A001            0
0002        A002                            A002            0
0005        A005                            A005            0

Table 2
0003        A003            A001        
0004        A004            A002        
0006        A006            A004        

SELECT  ID,
        Record_ID, *how to include ID from both table? Or don’t even separate? 
        Correction_ID, *same as above
        CASE
            WHEN Correction_ID is null THEN One.Original_Record
                ELSE (SELECT Original_Record FROM One WHERE Two.Correction_ID=One.Record_ID)
        END as Original_Record,
        CASE
            WHEN Count is not null THEN One.Count
                ELSE (SELECT Count FROM One WHERE Two.Correction_ID=One.Record_ID) + 1
        END as Count;
        FROM Table 1 AS One, Table 2 AS Two;
```

Comment: What steps have you tried to add these variables and what was the result?

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far in the question.

Comment: @Joe I have tried using proc SQL but it didn't work. I consulted a co-worker and was told to use three temp arrays for Record_ID, Original_Record, Count and do iterations on those. But given my current knowledge I don't think I am able to do that.

Comment: @ Adam B see edit. Since then I have played around with dynamic macros and I think I might have a crude solution. Involving a lot of renaming, sorting, merging etc, which does not seem to be efficient enough. Perhaps that is why my co-worker suggested temp arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems working for your data as is. It leverages Hash object, where 'Original_Record' is retained and 'count' is added up. Some of the elements maybe redundant for now ('_start' maybe not needed).

```
data have;
    infile cards truncover;
    input (ID      Record_ID   Correction_ID) (:$8.);
    cards;
0001    A001    
0002    A002    
0003    A003        A001
0004    A004        A002
0005    A005    
0006    A006        A004
0007    A007        
0008    A008        A006
0009    A009        A003
;;;;
run;

data want;
    if _n_=1 then
        do;
            declare hash h();
            h.definekey('_end');
            h.definedata('_end', '_start', '_origin', 'count');
            h.definedone();
            length _end _start _origin $ 8;
            /*call missing (of _:, count);*/
        end;

    set have;

    if missing (correction_id) then
        do;
            original_record=record_id;
            count=0;
        end;
    else
        do;
            rc=h.find(key:correction_id);

            if rc ne 0 then
                    do;
/*if there is no match, this would be the first time of modifying, '_origin' is set to the value of correction_id, count is set to 1*/
                    _origin=correction_id;
                    count=1;
                end;
            else
                do;

/*if there is a match, then '_origin stays the same, so no  
operation is needed, but count increased by 1*/
                    count=count+1;
                end;

            _end=record_id;
            _start=correction_id;
            Original_Record=_origin;
            rc=h.replace();
        end;

    drop rc _:;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've adopted the solution in my problem. Could you what this "if rc ne 0 then do; _origin=correction_id; count=1; end;" trying to code for? Or if you might, just provide some comments on the rest of the code as well?

Comment: Some comments were just added.

Comment: Thanks, so the rc=h.find(key:correction_id); checks to see if the correction_id is in the hash object and basically sets everything to count =1 the first time, and the subsequent times the count gets +1 everytime the correction_id shows up in the hash defined by _origin or _end?

Comment: That is correct, but not just check, it also brings back if there is a match. So make sure you understand the reason why Find method instead of Check method is used here.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll read up more on hash in SAS to confirm my understandings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SAS/OR license, then this code does roughly the same, but more simply, since PROC OPTMODEL arrays are hashes. It does load all the data into RAM, so the price of simplicity is memory consumption.

I'll reuse Haikuo's data set:

```
 data have;
    infile cards truncover;
    input (ID      Record_ID   Correction_ID) (:$8.);
    cards;
    0001    A001    
    0002    A002    
    0003    A003        A001
    0004    A004        A002
    0005    A005    
    0006    A006        A004
    0007    A007        
    0008    A008        A006
    0009    A009        A003
;
```

I don't think we really need `ID`, so I ignored it to make the code more illustrative. It is not used internally, but you can add it to the `read data` and `create data` statements if you need to.

```
proc optmodel;
    set<str,str> RECORDS;
    set ALL = setof{<i,j> in RECORDS} i;
    str parent  {ALL diff {<i,('')> in RECORDS}};
    str original{i in ALL} init i;
    num count   {     ALL} init 0;

    read data have into RECORDS=[Record_Id Correction_ID];
    for {<ri,rj> in RECORDS: rj ~= ''} do;
        parent  [ri] = rj;
        count   [ri] = count   [parent[ri]] + 1;
        original[ri] = original[parent[ri]];
    end;
    create data want from [Record_ID Correction_ID]=RECORDS 
        Original_Record = original[Record_ID] Count = count[Record_ID];
quit;
```

Comment: Hello Leo, unfortunately I only have access to Base SAS but thank you for taking your time to write out the codes.

Comment: No worries! Hopefully it will be useful to someone who Googles this.